# Run different functions in specific order

Tags: loops, autoit

I'm trying to run different functions X amount of times and in a specific order.

```
Global $Runner
HotKeySet("{F8}", "start")
HotKeySet("{F9}", "stop")

While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func start()
   Local $1 = 0
   Local $2 = 1
   Local $3 = 44
    $Runner = Not $Runner
    While $Runner
       If $1 <= $2 Then
         <rune some code>
         <$1 = $1 + 1>
       ElseIf $1 >= $2 Then
         <run some other code>
         <$1 = 0>               ; To star the loop again
       Until $1 has run 44 times Then
         <last piece of code>
       EndIf
    WEnd
EndFunc   ;==>start

Func stop()
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>stop
```

I declared three variables:

```
$1 = 0
$2 = 1
$3 = 44
```

I'm trying to run it in a way that:

```
If $1 <= $3 Then
  <rune some code>
Else $1 >= $3 Then
  <run some other code>
;then repeat from start
Until $1 has run 44 times Then
<last piece of code>
```

I don't know how to make the third code run after the first has done 44 loops. Any tips on how I can do this as easily as possible? The order should be:

- [First code] should always run two times.
- [Second code] should always run after the [first code] has looped two times, then in between every loop
- [Third code] should always run after the first code has looped 44 times.

Comment: `for $i = 1 to 44 <your code> next`

Answer (score 0):

```
$flag = 1

For $i = 1 To 44

    If $i = 44 Then              ;every 44th time
        MsgBox(0, $i , 'run $3') ;do thing 3
        $i = 0                   ;reset the loop we are counting to 44 with
        ContinueLoop
    EndIf

    If $flag = 3 Then            ;every third time
        MsgBox(0, $i , 'run $2') ;do thing 2
        $flag = 1                ;reset the flag we are counting to 3 with
        ContinueLoop
    EndIf

    If $flag < 3 Then            ;every first and second time
        MsgBox(0, $i , 'run $1') ;do thing 1
        $flag += 1               ;iterate the flag we are counting to 3 with
        ContinueLoop
    EndIf

Next
```

Answer (score -1):

> … how I can do this as easily as possible?

As per [Documentation - Language Reference - Loop Statements](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/lang_loops.htm):

> A loop is how you refer to a section of script that you repeat a number of times. You might want to loop a given number of times or you might wish to repeat a section of script as long as a certain condition is true or false.

Example:

```
While True

    For $i1 = 1 To 44

        For $i2 = 1 To 2

            ConsoleWrite($i1 & ' function1' & @CRLF)

        Next

        ConsoleWrite($i1 & ' function2' & @CRLF)

    Next

    ConsoleWrite($i1 & ' function3' & @CRLF)

WEnd
```

Infinitely repeats:

```
1 function1
1 function1
1 function2
...
44 function1
44 function1
44 function2
45 function3
```

Explanation of intended order leaves room for interpretation; whatever intention is easily achieved moving loops or function-calls up or down a level.